# Core data created with Objective C and fetch from Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data, realm-migration

I have an App which is using core data and written in Objective C.Here we are not using persistentContainer.

Now we re-written the full application in Swift and this App is using Realm.

I want to migrate one DB entity from core data to realm and delete core data file after this.

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "HitList")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
      if let error = error as NSError? {
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
      }
    })
    return container
  }()

 var personData: [NSManagedObject] = []
            let managedContext = self.persistentContainer.viewContext

            let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Person")
            do {
                offlineData = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }


            if  (personData.count) > 0 { // Insert DB into Relam

            }
```

I am getting following errors

error:  Failed to load model named HitList
CoreData: error:  Failed to load model named HitList

During fetch following error was thrown.

Could not fetch. Error Domain=Foundation._GenericObjCError Code=0 "(null)", [:]

What is wrong?

Comment: Do you have a bridging header file for the core data objects?

Comment: I don't have the .h and .m file of Objective C in swift Application is it required?

Comment: A lot could be wrong. If your model has not changed then it seems you are incorrectly loading your data. You can go step by step in your code and see what is going on which may be a lot of code for initialisation of your core data... But you could avoid ALL of this. Simply leave it in objective C and use bridging to swift for your migration instead of porting your code that you are deprecating anyway. To make things even better I suggest you create a new project with your old code and make it a library/framework which may then be included in your swift project.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is that the CoreData stack from Objective C saves the database to a different path than the persistentContainer. Therefore, it won't find it because it's looking in a different location.
You can connect a device and check it with iExplorer and you'll see.
To migrate it, you need to reference the location.